# How can i change Firebase storage image file name which is already uploaded?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-storage

I need to change the file name which is already uploaded in firebase storage. Because, after uploading a image in firebase storage, i save the url in firebase database under a specific child(folder). But when i move the image to another child(folder), i need to change the image file name in storage according to new name. How can i do this? Firebase metadata has a name property, but it is readonly property.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot change the filename of the image that is already uploaded to firebase storage. 
What you can do is

Step 1: download the given image from the storage

Step 2: Convert the UIImage to data by using `UIImagePNGRepresentation` of `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` methods.

Step 3: Create a reference using the desired name `Storage.storage().reference().child("DesiredName")`

Step 4: Upload the data to firebase storage `.putData`

Step 5: Delete the previously uploaded data from firebase.

```
// Create a reference to the file to delete
let desertRef = storageRef.child("desert.jpg")
// Delete the file
desertRef.delete { error in
   if let error = error {
   // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
   } else {
   // File deleted successfully
   }
}
```