# Is there a way to rename file in firebase storage using flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, file-rename

I am uploading the files according the timestamp. Now when user update the information. I have to update the fileName according to current timestamp. So, is it possible to update the file name?

**Note: We can delete the older information and create new ones.**

But, I want to know if there is any edit option.

Comment: There are no move or rename operations provided by the Firebase SDKs. You would have to write code to download the file, upload it again with the new name, then delete the original.  It's better if you don't rely on the name of files in storage.  Instead, it's easier to manage data about files in a database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in another answer, the filename can't be directly changed.

One option is to download the file, delete it and the upload a new file with a new name.

Another option is to leverage cloud functions to perform that task

The first two options use a lot of bandwidth and if the files are large or changes are frequent, it can drive costs up.

Things like filenames can be dynamic and it's often a good practice to break the link between the filename and the file itself.

When writing a file, I would create a generic filename but then store the user-facing name in Firestore. So here's what Firestore would look like, each document in the images collection has a documentId which matches the image name stored in storage and the url reference

```
firestore
   images (collection)
      image_0 (auto-generated id created with Swift .addDocument or Java .add for example)
         name: "Picture of a Leroy"
         url: "www....."
         timestamp: "20200722"
      image_1
         name: "Picture of Sally"
         url: "www....."
         timestamp: "20200725"
```

as you can see, with this structure you can change the name of the document easily with very little overhead or cost and it's super quick.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is, that there is not an option to edit file names after they have been uploaded to Firebase Storage for no API (even not with Flutter).

But there are some workarounds in theory:

- A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47036485/5508719) for an iOS implementation received an answer, that you can download first the image, delete it then from the storage and then reupload it with the new timestamp, as you noted in your question.
- But how I would implement this case is, that you always use the Storage module from Firebase in combination with the Firestore. So there, you link the image in Firestore and just update the timestamp in an object there. Here an example:

```js
{
   "image_path": "/images/1595765336.jpg" //The filename contains the original timestamp, when it was uploaded.
   "timestamp:" 1595765336 //Now you can update just this value and the reference to the image remains the same.
   // And of course you can add additional parameters as you want.
}
```

The second option is maybe a better solution, when you don't want to consume too much data from the user, since you just update the timestamp and not the whole image, even if it remains the same.