# Get a custom name on downloading file from Firebase Storage

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

Let's say I have a file into a Storage Bucket with path as `some/path/myFile.extension`

I'm trying to download it from web using

```js
const storage = new Storage();
const downloadUrl = await storage.ref('some_path_myFile.extension').getDownloadURL();
```

This code allow me to get an URL used into an HTML anchor tag.
My problem is that the name of the file is equal to the Storage path (with "/" replaced by "_".).
*some_path_myFile.extension* <- This is the storage path wth "/" replaced by "_".

I tried to use the download attribute of HTML anchor tag to pass a custom name, but it didn't works.

Currently my render is:

```js
<IconButton aria-label="download" size="small" href={downloadUrl} target="_blank">
  <GetAppIcon fontSize="inherit" />
</IconButton>
```

Do you guys have an idea please ? Thank you community

Comment: Can you edit your question and share a screenshot of what the filename looks like and also your HTML/JS code that you are currently using to show the image? Also where is `fileDoc` coming from ?

Comment: Thanks for adding the details. It's a bit unclear about the / _ part. Can you please share a screenshot from Firebase Storage console to show the file path.

Comment: I edited the question, trying to be more explicit TY

Comment: you can refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63099309/is-there-a-way-to-rename-file-in-firebase-storage-using-flutter) which is a similar issue.